# Trying to console.log 2 inputs from a Prompt

Tags: javascript

I have 2 questions I want the user to answer and want the console.log to put those answer together. I've been successful with 1 question but cannot figure out how to get 2. I know I'm way off but, this is what I have so far.

```
        var EventType = prompt("What kind of Event are you attending?");
        var tempFahr = prompt("What is the temperature?");

        if( EventType == "semi-formal" ) {
           console.log("Wear a polo ");
        } else if( EventType == "casual" ) {
           console.log("Wear something comfy ");
        } else if( EventType == "formal" ) {
           console.log("Wear a suit");
        } else {
           console.log("Wear nothing!");
        }


        if( tempFahr <= 70 ) {
           console.log("It is hot outside!");
        } else if( tempFahr >= 54 ) {
           console.log("It's chilly outside!");
        } else if( tempFahr < 54 + >70 ) {
           console.log("It is pleasant outside");
        } else {
           console.log("Who cares about the weather,");
        }
```

Comment: I have this at the top:

var EventType = prompt("What kind of Event are you attending?");
var tempFahr = prompt("What is the temperature?");

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to tackle this, but the simplest is probably just assigning to a results variable.

```
    var EventType = prompt("What kind of Event are you attending?");
    var tempFahr = prompt("What is the temperature?");

    var recommendedClothing
    if( EventType == "semi-formal" ) {
       recommendedClothing = "Wear a polo ";
    } else if( EventType == "casual" ) {
       recommendedClothing = "Wear something comfy ";
    } else if( EventType == "formal" ) {
       recommendedClothing = "Wear a suit";
    } else {
       recommendedClothing = "Wear nothing!";
    }

    var weatherAssessment
    if( tempFahr <= 70 ) {
       weatherAssessment = "It is hot outside!";
    } else if( tempFahr >= 54 ) {
       weatherAssessment = "It's chilly outside!";
    } else if( tempFahr < 54 || tempFahr > 70 ) {
       weatherAssessment = "It is pleasant outside";
    } else {
       weatherAssessment = "Who cares about the weather,";
    }

    console.log(recommendedClothing + ' ' + weatherAssessment)
```

**Edit**

A few other notes, because it seems you might still be learning (great first question btw!)

- Pick a consistent case for your variables (I would probably rename EventType to eventType so its the same case as tempFahr)
- The `54 + >70` is probably not behaving how'd you expected. Have a look into logical operators, namely `&&` and `||`

Comment: Thanks! You are correct in that I'm just learning! I appreciate the help!

Comment: No worries mate, good luck with your learning journey. If the answer proved helpful, you can mark it as correct which assists future users reading this question by indicating what was the solution that worked

Comment: I'm still getting some syntax errors but this has been helpful!

Comment: The syntax error is most likely related to the `54 + >70`

Comment: Without spoiling the whole thing, you will need something like `} else if( tempFahr < 54 && tempFahr > 70 ) {`

Comment: I saw that and changed to tempFahr <54 || >70 but it's still being a bugger

Comment: you're close. take a close look at my last comment (i'll also edit my answer)

Comment: Also, start looking at switch cases https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp. It is better than else if else if else if else if....

Comment: "better" is subjective, and switch actually wouldn't work very well in your scenario above (not for the weather section anyway). my advice is to learn about both, learn how to use both, and over time you will understand when to use both. also, try mdn instead of w3schools

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I was going to try it with a switch case but I'm trying to wrap my head around the if else stuff. I appreciate the help though! You're an absolute legend!